# Replacing decimals with a space at the end of a fixed-with string

Tags: c#, .net, string

Alright, so I have a working program that makes golden ratio rectangles based on a length or width given.

[image: Program Shown.]
This probably isn't a good practice, but I wrote a *String.Slice(start, end)* in the extensions class.

**Here's what I need help with.**

```
            case 1: //Length
                l1.Text = value.ToString().Slice(0, 4);
                l2.Text = value.ToString().Slice(0, 4);
                h1.Text = (value/phi).ToString().Slice(0, 4);
                h2.Text = (value/phi).ToString().Slice(0, 4);
                break;
            case 2: //Width
                l1.Text = (value * phi).ToString().Slice(0, 4);
                l2.Text = (value * phi).ToString().Slice(0, 4);
                h1.Text = value.ToString().Slice(0, 4);
                h2.Text = value.ToString().Slice(0, 4);
                break;
```

Depending on the radiobutton, it finds the length or with based on what you provide. The problem is that with the strings all sliced to 1-4 characters, a number can be shown as

```
 "161."
```

(with the period) in the textbox. Is there a way to make it so that only if it ends with a period that the period is removed? Thanks.

P.S. Here's the slice function for reference:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string Slice(this string source, int start, int end)
    {
        if (end < 0) // Keep this for negative end support
        {
            end = source.Length + end;
        }
        int len = end - start;               // Calculate length
        try
        {
            return source.Substring(start, len); // Return Substring of length
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            try
            {
                return source.Substring(start, len - 1); // Return Substring of length
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                try
                {
                    return source.Substring(start, len - 2); // Return Substring of length
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return source.Substring(start, len - 3); // Return Substring of length
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make that `Slice` function go away. The flow control via exception handling makes my eyes hurt.

Comment: nesting try/catch blocks this way is a bad programming practice. instead of trying len, len-1, len-2... you can just dynamically find out the required length of string to return and just return that. (i really didn't understand what you are exactly doing, that's why i'm not answering the question) just think this: what if you needed to handle not 4 but 100 cases? would you write 100 nested try catch blocks? that would definitely work, but is a really bad practice and not feasible. avoid using try catch unless you have to, and avoid nesting any kind of blocks this much.

Comment: I'm new to the language and didn't know what to do, but I have used ruby/python and am used to the slice. Don't really know how to dynamically find the length and then cut it.

Comment: What happens if I enter a big number, like 10000 as width? Won't keeping only 4 characters display an incorrect answer?

Comment: I had to keep the input's maxlength at 4 as a limiter, which is even worse for functionality.

Comment: @shbaldw: and which is probably still wrong. What if I enter 9999 as _width_?

Comment: @jods Oh. Well, now I've more reasons to switch to a format string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using this strange Slice() function? Wouldn't it be enough to use String.Format with a special [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)? For example instead of writing

```
h1.Text = (value/phi).ToString().Slice(0, 4);
```

just write:

```
h1.Text = String.Format("{0:0.0}", value/phi);
```

...and so on?

Comment: +1 This is how numbers are generally formatted in .net. Or the shorter: (value/phi).ToString("0.0");

Comment: I'm using it, as I'm used to other languages and don't (know how to) use a format too much.